Installing Windows 11 in a VM on Ubuntu 24.04
I have Windows 11 preinstalled on my laptop and I don't have Ubuntu.
I want to have Ubuntu 24.04 LTS as base operating system and run Windows 11 in Virtual box. I want to my existing Windows account and data intact in the virtual machine. What should I do?

The easy answer is you install Ubuntu and wipe Windows. But it sounds like you may not have the info to reinstall Windows. Suggest you do some research on using Virtual Box before you start.

Want to reinstall Windows again on Virtual Box with my previous Windows account and data intact. What should I do ?

Up to you to back up the data  Windows will be a new install.

You could clone the drive, but this is going to be more trouble than it is worth.  Best to back-up critical data.  As for the Windows account - Not really a problem since you can simply log in again in the VM.  However, the Windows license is going to be the issue.  The license that the laptop OEM provided will not transfer to the virtual machine, so I'm fairly certain you'll need to purchase another Windows license in order to use the VM for more than 30 days.

It seems that your Windows 11 laptop is a recent enough model that it has more than enough disk space to support a dual boot. Dual booting Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 11 is a much better option for the following reasons.

Running Windows 11 in a virtual machine will always have performance limitations compared to the preinstalled Windows 11.
✅ Dual booting ensures that both operating systems run directly on the hardware, leading to better stability and reliability.
Dual booting allows for more efficient resource allocation between the two operating systems.
Applications that rely on specific hardware features or specific drivers might not function correctly in a virtualized environment.
Some software licenses restrict usage in virtual environments.

The second reason is the most important one. Time after time I have seen the VirtualBox guest OS fail with no option left except to reinstall the OS. This isn't such a big deal if the guest OS is Ubuntu, but I don't consider this to be acceptable if the guest OS is Windows because it takes too long to fully rebuild the whole pre-existing system.

"What should you do?" see the dual boot answer.  You can install a Windows 11 VM on Ubuntu 24.04, I did that, but don't use it for much other than patches;^).  Here's what I did for Win 11 24h2:

install the swtpm package. This will get the necessary software for the TPM check that Windows performs. In theory, you can run this manually, but the instructions I found didn't actually work -- virt-manger will automatically pick up and run this correctly (what it runs has many more parameters than the manual instructions).

2)Download and hashcheck your selected Windows ISO.  24h2 has not actually been officially released yet, but is available for download.  Try it, but maybe 23h2 is the one to select. These "feature updates" expire after two years (no more patches), so get the latest. Don't expect the later feature updates to be offered, expect to have to reinstall.
3)The minimum VM is 50-55 GB, but the actual used space on a fresh install will take 25-30GB. The virt-manager install was straightforward, with the swtpm installed, it should just work.
4)The "activation" = license will not be picked up from your base machine. An unactivated machine still gets all the patches and runs. Supposedly, after a trial period, the background becomes blue with an activation nag displayed. I don't find this happening on my Win 11 VMs (23h2 and 24h2) after many months -- maybe since I use them so little.
5)The cheap "activation" keys ($20-$30) you see online may or may not work. Supposedly the keys are "scraped" off old machines or are OEM keys, but by the time you find they don't work, your refund will be rejected because you downloaded the key. Calling Microsoft and begging to have them unblock the key is never a part of the advertisement.
The official keys cost $150-$200, so if you insist on activation, the dual boot approach comes with the machine license.

It has been a while since I ran a duel boot system (WIN 10 with Ubuntu 20), but I ran into significant issues as most major Windows updates would break the duel boot. By that I mean, the option to boot into my Ubuntu drive would be removed (I used physically separate HDDs for each OS with a shared external). I would have to recreate the boot option for Ubuntu quite a bit. I even went so far as getting a switch for my drives to 'force' the boot to the powered OS drive. Even this ultimately didn't work.
I am looking at doing something similar again as WIN 11 has been giving me grief with graphic display errors with my GPU. I also have to force group policy/admin rules to prevent feature updates that ultimately cause chaos on my system. One of my was to use a shared partition or NAS that Ubuntu and WIN can read/write to (all my files, pictures, music, etc.) and then load all my WIN SW on the VM. As mentioned by others there will be stability issues and if using VirtualBox there will be unrecoverable crashes. So, create a copy of your fresh VM you can use to restore.
Another thing to consider is what your application needs for Windows. If you don't need all the bells and whistles, maybe consider using Windows 11 Lite (https://beebom.com/how-install-windows-11-lite/). This may provide better stability and performance. However, keep in mind that this is not an official WIN 11 OS.
I know this is a detailed listing of how-to, but wanted to pass on my previous experience.

Can Windows 11 Lite be updated or does it run perpetually without ever being updated?

~Accidentally submitted comment and then edit time ran out.
Once the lite version is installed it will run perpetually. Most are experimental versions of Microsoft's Windows 11, so make sure to understand all the security implications of these changes. Having a small OS footprint will reduce the resources needed for a VM running Windows 11. So, would be interesting to see the results. Keep us posted.
This article gives some good details.
https://geekflare.com/install-windows-11-lite-version-tiny11/
